# When does a stable endomorphism ring have injective dimension at most one?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, gap

tLet $A$ be a Frobenius algebra (we can assume that $A$ is given by quiver and relations) and let $M$ be a basic $A$-module without projective direct summands (we can assume we know the decomposition of $M$ into indecomposable modules $M_i$).

Let $B:=\underline{Hom_A}(M,M)$ be the stable endomorphism ring of $M$.

> Question 1: Is there a method to determine inside the stable category of $A$ whether $B$ has injective dimension at most one as a $B$-module? Is this possible using the GAP-package QPA?

Here my thought on this:
The indecomposable projective $B$-modules are given by $\underline{Hom_A}(M,M_i)$ and having injective dimension at most one is equivalent to the existence of short exact sequences of the form

$0 \rightarrow \underline{Hom_A}(M,M_i) \rightarrow D(\underline{Hom_A}(X_0,M)) \rightarrow D(\underline{Hom_A}(X_1,M)) \rightarrow 0$.

Here $X_i \in add(M)$.

Now by the Auslander-Reiten formulas and using $Ext_A^1(-,-) \cong \underline{Hom_A}(\Omega^1(-),-)$ in a Frobenius algebra we obtain:

$D(\underline{Hom_A}(X_i,M)) = D(\underline{Hom_A}(\tau^{-1}(\tau(X_i)),M) = Ext_A^1(M,\tau(X_i)) = \underline{Hom_A}(\Omega^1(M),\nu \Omega^2(X_i)) = \underline{Hom_A}( M , \nu \Omega^1(X_i)))$.

Thus the existence of the above short exact sequence is equivalent to an exact sequence of the form

$0 \rightarrow \underline{Hom_A}(M,M_i) \rightarrow \underline{Hom_A}(M,\nu \Omega^1(X_0)) \rightarrow \underline{Hom_A}(M,\nu \Omega^1(X_1)) \rightarrow 0$.

This makes it look like it can be decided whether $B$ has injective dimension one by looking at short exact sequences in the stable module category of $A$ of the following form:

$0 \rightarrow M_i \rightarrow \nu \Omega^1(X_0) \rightarrow \nu \Omega^1(X_1) \rightarrow 0$
with $X_i \in add(M)$. Is there a nice characterisation (and how to find the $X_i$) for the existence of such short exact sequences that can be checked using QPA?

> Question 2: Is there a more general characterisation when $B$ has finite injective dimension at most $n$ for some $n \geq 1$?

> Question 3: Can a minimal projective resolution of the simple $B$-module be found using properties of the stable module category of $A$ that can be obtained using QPA?

Maybe those questions already have an answer in the literature but I did not find anything.

Note that it is possible with QPA to calculate the stable endomorphism ring of $M$ but sadly this takes very long and never finished for non-small examples.